# Closure in different spaces example(check solution).

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we set $X$ = {a,b,c,d}, $Z$ = {b,d} and $Y$ = {d}.

It means: $Y \subset Z \subset X$

Z is subspace of X, Y is subspace of Z.

I define topology on $X$:

$T$ = {$X$,$\emptyset$,{a},{b,c},{a,b,c}}

Closed sets in topology $T$ are: {b,c,d},{a,d},{d}

Closure in $Y$ is intersection of all closed sets, which contains $Y$

Closure of Y in X: $Cl(Y)$ = {d}

Closure of Y in Z: $Cl(Y)$ = {d}

Are my calculations correct? If you, can provide examples, where closures of $Y$ in $X$ and in $Z$ are different?

If I am wrong, correct me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\varnothing$ and $X$ are also closed sets of topology $T$ don't forget them.

Here since $\{d\}$ is a closed set of the initial set $X$, the closure $\bar Y$ will stay the same whether you consider initial topology or any induced subspace topology that contains $Y$ (i.e. $\bar Y=Y$).

So to make a more interesting example take an $Y$ which is nor open nor closed. For instance let's take $Y=\{c,d\}$.

In $X$ then $\operatorname{Cl}_X(Y)=\{b,c,d\}$

Now let's take $Z=\{a,c,d\}$

The subspace topology is given by:

$T_Z=\{\varnothing\cap Z,X\cap Z,\{a\}\cap Z,\{b,c\}\cap Z,\{a,b,c\}\cap Z\}=\{\varnothing, Z,\{a\},\{c\},\{a,c\}\}$

Consequentyl the closed sets are $\{\varnothing, Z,\{c,d\},\{a,d\},\{d\}\}$

Thus in $Z$ we have $\operatorname{Cl}_Z(Y)=\{c,d\}=Y$